# What is the pullback of an alternating multilinear map

Tags: differential-forms, multilinear-algebra

I'm trying to understand the proof of the statement which says that up to multiplication by a nonzero scalar, there is a unique left invariant volume form on a lie group G. What I don't understand in this proof  is what is $L_g^*\omega_e$, Where $L_g$ is the left  translation by $g \in G$ and $\omega_e$ is $\wedge^n(T_eG)^*$. I know what is the pullback of differential form by a map but in this case $\omega_e$ is not a differential form on G it's an alternating multilinear map. So in general if V is a vector space of dimension n  and $\phi : V \rightarrow V $ is a map and $T \in \wedge^n V^*$  what is the definition of $\phi^*(T)$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pullback of $T \in \bigwedge^nW^*$ by a linear map $\phi : V \to W$ is defined by

$$(\phi^*T)(v_1, \dots, v_n) = T(\phi(v_1), \dots, \phi(v_n)).$$

Once you have this definition, you can define the pullback of differential forms pointwise. That is, if $f : M \to N$ is a smooth map, we obtain a linear map $(f_*)_p : T_pM \to T_{f(p)}N$, so if $\alpha \in \Omega^n(N)$, we define $(f^*\alpha)_p := (f_*)^*_p\alpha_{f(p)}$, i.e.

$$(f^*\alpha)_p(v_1, \dots, v_n) := ((f_*)^*_p\alpha_{f(p)})(v_1, \dots, v_n) = \alpha_{f(p)}((f_*)_pv_1, \dots, (f_*)_pv_n)$$

for all $v_1, \dots, v_n \in T_pM$.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! Appreciate it.